# Globally toggle between the use of mocked services in Angular 2

Tags: service, mocking, angular

We are working on our Angular 2 project and are looking for a way to swap all injections to our services with mocked versions with a single toggle.
We want to do this so we can detach ourselves from the backend if need be.

We want to be able to use dummy DTO's with hardcoded values by just changing a global property (mock = true)

Is it possible to configure the DI container of Angular 2 in such a way that by changing a global property, injected services are replaced by mocked ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create and provide your custom implementation of `XHRBackend` that forwards to `XHRBackend` or `MockBackend` depending on the setting of a global service.

Comment: Great, straightforward and easy to implement. I like!

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide dummy syntax example that works with @NgModule ?

Comment: Something like `@NgModule({ imports: [HttpModule], providers: [{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MyCustomHttpBackend}] })` or `TestBed.configureTestingModule(imports: [HttpModule], providers: [{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MyCustomHttpBackend}])`